# XSL to capture URL Params

Tags: xslt, restful-url

Not able to extract the params using XSLT,
for eg.: `http://www.example.com/AB/100/123456/09/8`

using XSLT need to extract like var1=AB, Var2=100, Var3=123456, var4=09, var5=8, All the params are mandatory. and var3 can accept 1-999999, could somebody share some ideas

tried Substring but it didn't help much

Comment: Through what interface does your XSLT have access to the URI in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the input is not clear, just as example: given an input XML

```
<root>
  <url>http://www.example.com/AB/100/123456/09/8</url>
</root>
```

following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="url">
    <xsl:call-template name="parse">
        <xsl:with-param name="url" select="substring-after(.,'//')" />
        <xsl:with-param name="position" select="1" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="parse">
    <xsl:param name="url" />
    <xsl:param name="position" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(substring-after($url, '/'),'/')">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('Var', $position, ': ')" />
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($url, '/'),'/')" />
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="parse">
                <xsl:with-param name="url" select="substring-after($url, '/')" />
                <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$position + 1" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('Var', $position, ': ')" />
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($url,'/')" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

produces the ouput

```
Var1: AB, Var2: 100, Var3: 123456, Var4: 09, Var5: 8
```

using the template `parse` which recursively calls itself when the `url` contains a `/`.

For every call the parameter `url` is reduced using `substring-after()` and the parameter `position` is incremented.